# FFmpeg youtube stream get corrupted until restart

Tags: python, linux, ffmpeg, stream

I am streaming images from python to youtube using ffmpeg.
It's working fine with just one problem.
Sometimes the stream get somehow corrupted an the stream looks like this:

[Corrupted stream image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTjka.png)

Or you can see for yourself in the stream itself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PG6NLtr0jjM (Scroll back to the beginning)

Then I have to restart ffmpeg and its working fine. Sometimes an error occurs regarding the network and I have to automatically restart the stream. Then there is the possibility it is corrupted again.

The parameters for ffmpeg are the following:

```
cmd_out = ['ffmpeg',
       '-re',
       '-f', 'concat',
       '-i', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'music', 'music.txt').replace('\\', '/'),           
       '-r', '1',
       '-f', 'image2pipe',
       '-vcodec', 'png',
       '-r', '1',
       '-i', '-',
       '-c:v', 'libx264',
       '-c:a', 'copy',
       '-g', '4',
       '-f', 'flv',
       'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/{}'.format(stream_key)]
```

I never had that problem testing it on windows. It just appears when I use my linux server.

I am using **ffmpeg version 3.2.18-0+deb9u1** and the generated images are fine, when I save them to a normal file.

Does someone know how to fix it? Or where the problem is comming from?

---

**Solution:** An old ffmpeg version was available while using docker. I solved the problem by using a static build from https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

I used this to use it in docker:

```
WORKDIR /app
ADD ./ffmpeg /app
RUN mv ffmpeg /usr/local/ffmpeg
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/ffmpeg
```

Until now the error seems to be solved.

Comment: Please edit your Q to show what  version you have on Windows.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Look in the Main Thread for the solution.

Comment: You can post your own solution as an answer below and accept it after 48 hrs to gain valuable reputation points. However, in the future, questions about using software belong on [su] or possibly [unix.se]. Your's may be a corner case where you are developing software that uses a 3rd party software, so don't sweat it. Good luck.